# How to set proxy manually in CefSharp

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, cefsharp

I'm working on a CefSharp application,
[Downloaded from this link](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp). I want to set the proxy manually. I've applied `AutoDetectProxySettings = true`, but I'm not sure either it is working or not. In the sample

```
bool IRequestHandler.GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, ref string username, ref string password)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

I've marked a breakpoint there but it is not calling it.

Comment: try this: CefSharp.CefSettings settings = new CefSharp.CefSettings();
                settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-auto-detect", "1");CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);

Comment: try this, automatically detects proxy settings: CefSharp.CefSettings settings = new CefSharp.CefSettings(); settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-auto-detect", "1");CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);

Answer (score 0):

its working 
just in CefExample.cs
add

```
                    settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", proxy.ProxyAddress);
                settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-bypass-list", "127.*,192.168.*,10.10.*,193.9.162.*");
```

it will work

Comment: Do you need the "proxy-server" line in order for the "bypass-list" to work?  And is the bypass list a comma separated list?  I saw in an example that they used semi-colons instead. See: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L37

Comment: So it does require both proxy-server and bypass.

Answer (score -1):

AFAK it doesn't work currently. Look in discussions [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cefsharp/Nv6DexNsEdY) This is a boring problem...